# Spring mvc cannot find CacheInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I'm exploring cache in spring mvc framework. Following the guide on internet like [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) or [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/), i'm configuring:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
<cache:annotation-driven />
... other configuration are omitted....
</beans>
```

Before adding configuration for cache, my web app run normally, now, my web app start with error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheInterceptor
```

Not sure what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A *NoClassDefFoundError* is simply an exception that is thrown when java can't find a certain class that another library uses.

All this means is that when it gets thrown you just need to get it on the classpath. You can make sure it's there by going to libraries-> maven dependencies(if you are using maven) -> and then go to the location of the noclassdef that is being thrown, in your case it would be at org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheInterceptor, this is just so you know why you are getting this error, you should not see it now.

As for how to solve it, this could be happening because of 3 things:

1. Your maven dependencies are not on the deployment assemblies(libraries are in the project, but not on the server), although probably spring wouldn't work at all if this was the case.
2. You don't have the dependency, add this to pom.xml:

   org.springframework
               spring-context
               4.1.4.RELEASE
3. You have conflicting spring versions, make all version tags the same.

Comment: i don't use Maven at all. I'm newbie in Java world and i have never used Maven yet. And so, i have no pom.xml file. As you described, i think i have missed 1 or some libraries but still don't know how to get them.

Comment: @khoa_chung_89 well how did you get your other libraries? That's how you get any other libraries you need.

Comment: @khoa_chung_89 ok well i would definitely recommend learning java basics and maven before moving to Spring. That said if you aren't using maven download the jar file and add it manually.

Comment: @khoa_chung_89 But all the points i made still hold true even if you aren't using maven, just replace maven with installed jars

Comment: I have not added any jar relating to spring cache. I just create a basic spring web project and i think the cache library should be there by default. I have read some articles and they don't mention any library that i have to add to use spring cache. I agree that i should use maven but even though, how do i know what i missed ? If i have known exactly the problem (what the libraries are mis-matching version or what library is missing) i think i could solve it with or without maven.

Comment: @khoa_chung_89 spring cache is part of spring context, just add that jar